# SQL select rows with same id are all having the same value

Tags: sql, db2

I got a table like this:

```
+--------+------+-----+
|Provider|Type  |Date |
+--------+------+-----+
|1       |Meal  |Date1|
+--------+------+-----+
|1       |ACCOM |Date2|
+--------+------+-----+
|2       |Meal  |Date3|
+--------+------+-----+
|2       |Meal  |Date4|
+--------+------+-----+
|3       |ACCOM |Date5|
+--------+------+-----+
|3       |ACCOM |Date6|
+--------+------+-----+
```

A provider can provide either accommodation or meal on a date. **Is there a way i can select all providers who only provide meal or only provide accommodation?**

So i am expecting:

```
+--------+------+-----+
|2       |Meal  |Date3|
+--------+------+-----+
|2       |Meal  |Date4|
+--------+------+-----+
|3       |ACCOM |Date5|
+--------+------+-----+
|3       |ACCOM |Date6|
+--------+------+-----+
```

Since provider 2 only provides meal and provider 3 only provides accommodation.

### **UPDATE:**

The original question is:

> List all providers who only provide accommodations or meals (not
>   both).
>
> NOTE: do not eliminate duplicates in the result.

So I think i should get duplicates in one-step instead of joining table again.

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT PROVIDERS.PROVID AS ID
FROM PROVIDERS
INNER JOIN ISP ON ISP.PROVID = PROVIDERS.PROVID
WHERE ISP.SVCTYPE = 'ACCOM'

UNION ALL

SELECT PROVIDERS.PROVID AS ID
FROM PROVIDERS
INNER JOIN ISP ON ISP.PROVID = PROVIDERS.PROVID
WHERE ISP.SVCTYPE = 'MEAL'
```

***The problem is this query has duplicated code, the only difference is 'ACCOM' or 'MEAL' so can this query be improved again?***

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, it is removed.

Comment: Are you by chance creating dupe of airbnb or enhanced version?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way where you get only one row per provider:

```
select provider, min(type)
from t
group by provider
having min(type) = max(type);
```

If you actually want the duplicates then use `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select provider, min(type)
      from t
      group by provider
      having min(type) = max(type)
     ) tt
     on t.provider = p.provider;
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to show all the result(with duplicates)?

Comment: If I have another type other than meal and accommodation? would i still be able to use min and max function?

Comment: @Jackddddd . . . Yes. It is just checking that all the values are the same.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question again. I added the db2 tag since i need to run it on a db2 server. Would you mind taking a look at it again?

Comment: @Jackddddd . . . This should be fine on DB2.